# How to edit the node value correctly in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

In the following XML code I try to edit the text node 
`<key id="fileOriginalPath">/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/GBV626375266/content/streams/DERIVATIVE_COPY/626375266.pdf</key>` and make it shorter like this:

```
`<key id="fileOriginalPath">/GBV626375266/content/streams/DERIVATIVE_COPY/626375266.pdf</key>`
```

So the part `/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest` should be removed
That' s my XSLT for it, but the problem is that it doesn't make any changes to XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/"
    xmlns:xlin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record/key[@id='fileOriginalPath']/text()[. = '/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/GBV626375266/content/streams/DERIVATIVE_COPY/626375266.pdf']">GBV626375266/content/streams/DERIVATIVE_COPY/626375266.pdf</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That is the original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><mets:mets xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/">
<mets:amdSec ID="fid1-2-amd">
    <mets:techMD ID="fid1-2-amd-tech">
      <mets:mdWrap MDTYPE="OTHER" OTHERMDTYPE="dnx">
        <mets:xmlData>
          <dnx xmlns="http://www.exlibrisgroup.com/dps/dnx">
            <section id="generalFileCharacteristics">
              <record>
                <key id="label">Das physikalische Praktikum : Handbuch 2010 für Studentinnen und Studenten der Physik ; mit 21 Tabellen</key>
                <key id="fileMIMEType">application/pdf</key>
                <key id="note">Das physikalische Praktikum : Handbuch 2010 für Studentinnen und Studenten der Physik ; mit 21 Tabellen : application/pdf</key>
                <key id="fileOriginalPath">/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/GBV626375266/content/streams/DERIVATIVE_COPY/626375266.pdf</key>
              </record>
            </section>
            <section id="fileFixity">
              <record>
                <key id="fixityType">MD5</key>
                <key id="fixityValue">763faa0ad3bcbdf6618acecbc7044fb3</key>
              </record>
            </section>
          </dnx>
        </mets:xmlData>
      </mets:mdWrap>
    </mets:techMD>
    <mets:rightsMD ID="fid1-2-amd-rights">
      <mets:mdWrap MDTYPE="OTHER" OTHERMDTYPE="dnx">
        <mets:xmlData>
          <dnx xmlns="http://www.exlibrisgroup.com/dps/dnx"/>
        </mets:xmlData>
      </mets:mdWrap>
    </mets:rightsMD>
    <mets:sourceMD ID="fid1-2-amd-source">
      <mets:mdWrap MDTYPE="OTHER" OTHERMDTYPE="dnx">
        <mets:xmlData>
          <dnx xmlns="http://www.exlibrisgroup.com/dps/dnx"/>
        </mets:xmlData>
      </mets:mdWrap>
    </mets:sourceMD>
    <mets:digiprovMD ID="fid1-2-amd-digiprov">
      <mets:mdWrap MDTYPE="OTHER" OTHERMDTYPE="dnx">
        <mets:xmlData>
          <dnx xmlns="http://www.exlibrisgroup.com/dps/dnx"/>
        </mets:xmlData>
      </mets:mdWrap>
    </mets:digiprovMD>
  </mets:amdSec>
 </mets:mets>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `dnx` and everything under it, is in a default namespace.

You need to account for this in your XSLT, otherwise your xpath will look for elements in no namespace.

As you are you using XSLT 3.0 you can use `xpath-default-namespace` to handle it. (This is also available in XSLT 2.0).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mets="http://www.loc.gov/METS/"
    xmlns:xlin="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.exlibrisgroup.com/dps/dnx"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
```

As an aside, perhaps you make your template a bit more generic....

```
<xsl:template match="record/key[@id='fileOriginalPath']/text()[starts-with(., '/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 51)" />
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: And if you wanted to use a variable (or parameter), you can...

```
<xsl:param name="path" select="'/exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest'" />

<xsl:template match="record/key[@id='fileOriginalPath']/text()[starts-with(., $path)]">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(., string-length($path) + 1" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is it possible to define /exlibris1/transfer/lza-tib/submission.tib/ingest/ as a variable to be more flexible? This path isn't constant and it's not so comfortable to count chars for every new path that has to be cutted off

Comment: Yes, you can use a variable or parameter. I've amended my answer to show how.